# Not acting cod python programmer does not

Tags: python, html, function, urllib, html-parser

At the outset, I would like to emphasize that I am not a programmer.

---

I have already written this code but I can not run it.
I work with Visual Studio 2013, I  have the following problems:

- > print "Beginning %s" % tag --- invalid syntax
- > print sou*p*.find('div', {'id': 'bar'}).p.text ----- invalid syntax

This is code was written by me. It is designed to retrieve the contents of the selected tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Beginning %s" % tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag): 
        print "End %s tag" % tag
    def handledata(self, data):
        print "Data %s" % data
p = MyHTMLParser()
input = urllib.urlopen('http://php.com')
html = input.read()
input.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.feed(html))
print soup.find('div', {'id': 'bar'}).p.text
```

Comment: Which version of Python? `print text` is a `SyntaxError` in 3.x, use `print(text)`.

Comment: I think your problem is that you're running Python 2 code under Python 3, but after writing a partial answer, I see you've run into more than just a syntax problem. Using [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/2to3.html) may fix some problems, but not others (e.g. `HTMLParser` was removed from Python 3).